# How to use multiple channel id's in this code

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I use multiple channel id's in this code?

```js
    import selfcore from "selfcore";
    
    const client = new selfcore();
    const gateway = new selfcore.Gateway("ODQ4MDIzNxjc0MDxxx4Mzk0.YS45RA.xxxxxxxxxQYflQE");
    
    gateway.on("message", (m) => {
      if (m.channel_id === "882134793771425843") {
        let content = m.content ? m.content : { embeds: [m.embeds[0]] };
    
        client.sendWebhook("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxx/drO_0pcypQ03HFWAdVN799DpUQKVfUukvf8wM82IZxfGOEK0Mxxxxxxxxxxx",
          content
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please give some more information about your problem? What exactly are you trying to achive? Are you getting any errors? What is your code doing? Please take a [tour], learn [ask] and update your question :)

Comment: i want to mirror messag efrom one server to another
but i unable to use more than one channel how can i add more

Comment: Sounds a little bit better, now update this to the question pls :D

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of channel id's, then use [Array#includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];

if (ids.includes(m.channel_id)) {
   // Your code
}
```

Using the logical or operator is also an option

```js
if (m.channel_id == 'id1' || m.channel_id == 'id2') {
   // Your code
}
```